# Django Rest Framework Token Authentication

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have read the Django Rest Framework Guides and done all the tutorials. Everything seemed to make sense and work just how it should. I got basic and session authentication working as described.

[django rest framework - api guide](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide)

However, I'm struggling with the Token Authentication part of the documentation, it's a little lacking or does not go into as much depth as the tutorials.

[django-rest-framework - token authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication)

It says I need to create tokens for users but does state where in models.py?

Can someone explain the Token Authentication part of the documentation a little better for a first-timer?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

No, not in your models.py -- on the models side of things, all you need to do is include the appropriate app (`rest_framework.authtoken`) in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. That will provide a Token model which is foreign-keyed to User.

What you need to do is decide when and how those token objects should be created. In your app, does every user automatically get a token? Or only certain authorized users? Or only when they specifically request one?

If every user should always have a token, there is a snippet of code on the page you linked to that shows you how to set up a signal to create them automatically:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

(put *this* in a models.py file, anywhere, and it will be registered when a Django thread starts up)

If tokens should only be created at certain times, then in your view code, you need to create and save the token at the appropriate time:

```
# View Pseudocode
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

def token_request(request):
    if user_requested_token() and token_request_is_warranted():
        new_token = Token.objects.create(user=request.user)
```

Once the token is created (and saved), it will be usable for authentication.

Comment: whats the meaning of `post_save `?

Comment: @244boy  It's setting up `create_auth_token` as a [signal handler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/) so that whenever a `User` is saved (hence `post_save`), `create_auth_token` gets invoked.  Signals are django's internal lifecycle event handling mechanism.

Answer (score 95):

@ian-clelland has already provided the correct answer. There are just a few tiny pieces that wasn't mentioned in his post, so I am going to document the full procedures (I am using Django 1.8.5 and DRF 3.2.4):

1. Do the following things **BEFORE** you create the superuser. Otherwise, the superuser does not get his/her token created.
2. Go to **settings.py** and add the following:

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = (
       'rest_framework',
       'rest_framework.authtoken',
       'myapp',
   )

   REST_FRAMEWORK = {
       'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
           'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
       ),
       'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
           'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
       )
   }
   ```
3. Add the following code in *myapp*'s **models.py**:

   ```
   from django.db.models.signals import post_save
   from django.dispatch import receiver
   from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
   from django.conf import settings

   # This code is triggered whenever a new user has been created and saved to the database
   @receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
   def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
       if created:
           Token.objects.create(user=instance)
   ```

   Alternatively, if you want to be more explicit, create a file named **signals.py** under *myapp* project. Put the code above in it, then in **__init__.py**, write `import signals`
4. Open up a console window, navigate to your project dir, and enter the following command:

   ```
   python manage.py migrate
   python manage.py makemigrations
   ```

   Take a look in your database, a table named **authtoken_token** should be created with the following fields: key (this is the token value), created (the datetime it was created), user_id (a foreign key that references the auth_user table's id column)
5. create a superuser with `python manage.py createsuperuser`. Now, take a look at the **authtoken_token** table in your DB with `select * from authtoken_token;`, you should see a new entry has been added.
6. Using `curl` or a much simpler alternative [httpie](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie#installation) to test access to your api, I am using httpie:

   ```
   http GET 127.0.0.1:8000/whatever 'Authorization: Token your_token_value'
   ```

   That's it. From now on, for any API access, you need to include the following value in the HTTP header (**pay attention to the whitespaces**):

   ```
   Authorization: Token your_token_value
   ```
7. (Optional) DRF also provides the ability to return a user's token if you supply the username and password. All you have to do is to include the following in **urls.py**:

   ```
   from rest_framework.authtoken import views

   urlpatterns = [
       ...
       url(r'^api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token),
   ]
   ```

   Using httpie to verify:

   ```
   http POST 127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/ username='admin' password='whatever'
   ```

   In the return body, you should see this:

   ```
   {
       "token": "blah_blah_blah"
   }
   ```

That's it!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment. where does the token get matched ? Can we edit anything ?

Comment: @rrmo The tokens are stored in a database table named auth_token (or something similar, I cannot remember the exact name. The table only has three columns, primary key, token, and a foreign key to the user model). Every time an authentication request is received, I think the database table is fetched to compare the incoming token with the stored ones.

Comment: @Cheng Regarding Point#3: Putting code in **signals.py** and adding `import signals` in `__init__.py` raises `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet` in Django 1.9.

Comment: Bu how do you receive the token, for example from a mobile app, you generate the token using username and password (For example create a base64 token) and send it in the request?

Comment: @JesusAlmaral The token is created on the server side not client side. After the user fill out registration information and send it to the server to create an account, a token is created together with the account. Once the token has been created, you can send its value to the client side.

Comment: Wow thanks Chen!, I asked you another question on your blog (http://cheng.logdown.com/posts/2015/10/27/how-to-use-django-rest-frameworks-token-based-authentication) because I don´t know if it´s right to be asking here hehe, I hope you could help me a little more please

Comment: @JesusAlmaral check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475334/django-rest-framework-how-to-specify-error-code-when-raising-validation-error-in

Comment: Thanks for detailed information !
This worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

On Django 1.8.2 and rest framework 3.3.2 following all of the above was not enough to enable token based authentication.

Although REST_FRAMEWORK setting is specified in django settings file, function based views required @api_view decorator:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(['POST','GET'])
def my_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
       ...
```

Otherwise no token authentication is performed at all

Comment: Despite the few upvotes, this answer adds a very useful point: without the @api_view decorator, the views won't use the token auth. Maybe it could be added to the chosen answer.

Comment: Two and a half years later ... THANK YOU

Answer (score 16):

Just to add my two cents to this, if you've got a custom user manager that handles user creation (and activation), you may also perform this task like so:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
# Other imports

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, **kwargs):
        """
        This is your custom method for creating user instances. 
        IMHO, if you're going to do this, you might as well use a signal.

        """
        # user = self.model(**kwargs) ...
        Token.objects.create(user=user)

    #You may also choose to handle this upon user activation. 
    #Again, a signal works as well here.

    def activate_user(**kwargs):
        # user = ...
        Token.objects.create(user=user)
```

If you already have users created, then you may drop down into the python shell in your terminal and create Tokens for all the users in your db.

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token 
>>> for user in User.objects.all():
>>> ...    Token.objects.create(user=user)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 10):

There is a cleaner way to get the user token.

simply run manage.py shell

and then

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
u = User.objects.get(username='admin')
token = Token.objects.create(user=u)
print token.key
```

then a record should be found in table DB_Schema.authtoken_token

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the excellent answers here, I'd like to mention a better approach to token authentication: JSON Web Token Authentication. The implementation offered by http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/ is very easy to use.

The benefits are explained in more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29440242/1571826).

Answer (score 1):

JSON Web Token Authentication is a better alternative than Token Authentication. This project has implemented JWT Auth with Django (http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/) but currently the project is unmaintained.

For alternatives you can follow :  https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt