# How to add token authentication to REST API created with Django REST framework

Tags: django, rest, api-key

I dont really understand how this works but i want to add token authentication or a kinda API key authentication to my REST API clients. how do i go about this, like i want the API clients to have API key when connecting to the API, should this be on user based where each human user of the API has an API key,

Comment: Have you try reading DRF [official docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#tokenauthentication) on Token auth?

Comment: For anybody wanting to access your API externally, the answer is yes. For anybody using your own software and accessing your data internally, then they don't need to have an API key.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560228/how-to-use-tokenauthentication-for-api-in-django-rest-framework

Answer (score 1):

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication states how to do this and as @kannor pointed out, see [How to use TokenAuthentication for API in django-rest-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560228/how-to-use-tokenauthentication-for-api-in-django-rest-framework)

add to installed apps in `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
     ...
    'rest_framework.authtoken'
)
```

Edit your `models.py` and add the following below to add a "hook"/"event" for the on save of your users

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

and add the following to your `urls.py`

```
from rest_framework.authtoken import views
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token)
]
```