# Django REST Framework Auth Token

Tags: python, django, rest

I'm having a little trouble with Token Authentication in the Django REST Framework. From the docs I know it is a matter of implementing the following:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

token = Token.objects.create(user=...)
print token.key
```

Now my question is, what exactly goes in the argument of `Token.objects.create(user=...)`. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838128/django-rest-framework-token-authentication) helps and it says **That will provide a Token model which is foreign-keyed to User.** I'm not sure I understand this.

I have my own model of Users defined like so:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    userid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255L, unique=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255L, unique=True, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=64L, blank=True)
    registeredip = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    joindate = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Users'
```

How would I create a token for users that satisfy certain conditions in this case?

```
# View Pseudocode
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

def token_request(request):
    if user_requested_token() and token_request_is_warranted():
        new_token = Token.objects.create(user=request.user) #What goes here?
```

Any help or leads to any more documentation/examples would really help me out here. Thank you!

Comment: What's the error you're getting? It looks like the code is fine.

Comment: @kroolik It isn't an error per se. I'm just not sure what the argument should be in my case.

Comment: `Token.objects.create(user=<your user instance>)` creates a token for `<your user instance>`.  You can insert this statement into your view where users request tokens passing `request.user` in place of `<your user instace>`. Make sure that `request.user` is an instance of `User`, not `AnonymousUser`.

Answer (score 3):

to be sure: we are talking about Token authentication that is provided by django rest framework?

If so, this is very simple method, where there is a token (random 40 characters) that is used instead of username and password.

What is DRF delivering is a table (`Token`) where you need to create entries for your users, `Token` is referencing your user model (builtin or active custom model).

There are no tokens created initially, you need to create them.

There are several ways to create tokens, most common are:

- create token for all users using signal handler (on create)
- create tokens in background task (e.g. management tasks, runining from time to time and creates missing tokens)
- have a special api endpoint, that will create token on-demand, with other user authentication method to authorize user

Basically that mean, that somewhere in your code you need to create `Token` instance, referencing your user instance.

```
Token(user=user).save()
```

Now, few remarks:

- this implementation of tokens is rather rudimentary, e.g. you do not have any options to expire token, the only way is to regenerate token - this may be problematic if you want expiring sessions and/or multiple clients (remember - one token per user, not browser/session/device)
- tokens are created using poor random function
- tokens are stored in the database as plain text
- there are multiple packages that deliver better and more secure token implementations, the most advanced are [django-rest-framework-jwt](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt) and [django-rest-knox](https://github.com/James1345/django-rest-knox) (second one is simpler)

p.s.
python class names should be singular (Users->User)

Comment: Is using `urandom` to generate tokens really insecure? I would think that keeping the tokens secret once they are generated would be a bigger issue. 

I didn't know that the default DRF tokens are stored as plain text. If you use django-rest-knox and your database is leaked, wouldn't an attacker still be able to find valid tokens by brute force?

Comment: this implementation is cryptographically weak, that's why ssh from begining is using it's own implementation; theoretically even existing strong hashers used in django can be brute-forced, so yes it is possible, question how much time it will take to break and in most cases - is this time is enough to detect, fix and expire all the tokens - for sure this is much better than no crypto at all; I'm using jwt tokens (from many reasons) and it is pretty neat; still waiting for [HTTP Signature](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-cavage-http-signatures/) to be TheNewThing