# Django REST Framework how to specify error code when raising validation error in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an API endpoint that allow users to register an account. I would like to return HTTP 409 instead of 400 for a duplicate username.

Here is my serializer:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    username = CharField()

    def validate_username(self, value):
        if User.objects.filter(username=value).exists():
            raise NameDuplicationError()
        return value


class NameDuplicationError(APIException):
    status_code = status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT
    default_detail = u'Duplicate Username'
```

When the error is triggered, the response is: `{"detail":"Duplicate Username"}`. I realised that if I subclass APIException, the key `detail` is used instead of `username`.

I want to have this response instead `{"username":"Duplicate Username"}`

or I would like to specify a status code when raising a ValidationError:

```
def validate_username(self, value):
    if User.objects.filter(username=value).exists():
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Duplicate Username', 
                                          status_code=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT)
    return value
```

But this does not work as `ValidationError` only returns 400.

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can raise different exceptions like:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException
from django.utils.encoding import force_text
from rest_framework import status


class CustomValidation(APIException):
    status_code = status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
    default_detail = 'A server error occurred.'

    def __init__(self, detail, field, status_code):
        if status_code is not None:self.status_code = status_code
        if detail is not None:
            self.detail = {field: force_text(detail)}
        else: self.detail = {'detail': force_text(self.default_detail)}
```

you can use this in your serializer like:

```
raise CustomValidation('Duplicate Username','username', status_code=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT)
```

or

```
raise CustomValidation('Access denied','username', status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

Comment: ternary operator may be cleaner here, `self.status_code = status_code if status_code else status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR`

Comment: This is good, but as-is default values aren't provided for `detail`, `field` and `status_code` making them required on instantiation.  (is not None check won't happen)

Answer (score 17):

By default, raising `serializers.ValidationError` will  return  with `HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST`

But sometimes we would like to return  `ValidationError` with normal `200` status code, because [some](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/pull/599) libraries on the client side  can't parse  `json` response data  while response code is not `200`.

I tried this. but it's not worked:

```py
raise serializers.ValidationError({'message':'Invalid  email address'}, code=200)
```

So we can do this and it works:

```py
res = serializers.ValidationError({'message':'Invalid  email address'})
res.status_code = 200
raise res
```

Comment: Wow, I need to test this, it would be great as I encounter the same (the issuer of the POST requests expects 200 status code)

Comment: This is indeed a pretty clean solution. And yes this also works to raise a 409 conflict.

Answer (score 4):

Use django-rest-framework custom exception handler http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/

```
def custom_exception_handler(exc, context=None):
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)
    if response is not None:
         if response.data['detail'] == 'Duplicate Username':
            response.data['username'] = response.data.pop('detail')
        response.status_code = status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT
    return response
```

Comment: Great, this works. This function will become very complicated if I want to customise the exception for different views. As the number of views increases, this function will grow as well. I wonder if there is a scaleable solution.

Comment: you mean to override 'detail' ?

Comment: I mean if there are 3 exceptions that I want to override, then I will have a if..elif..elif structure in `custom_exception_handler`. The more exception I want to customise, the more ifs I will have to write in this method. Also, I need to remember which if branch is responsible for which view's which HTTP action. This can be a real issue down the line.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Anush Devendra's answer, it seems that raising anything else than a `ValidationError` will bypass the treatment done by DRF on other fields.

Considering this code from DRF in exceptions.py:

```py
def to_internal_value(self, data):
        [...]

        for field in fields:
            [...]
            try:
                validated_value = field.run_validation(primitive_value)
                if validate_method is not None:
                    validated_value = validate_method(validated_value)
            except ValidationError as exc:
                errors[field.field_name] = exc.detail
            [...]
            else:
                set_value(ret, field.source_attrs, validated_value)

        if errors:
            raise ValidationError(errors)

        return ret
```

If you want to have this kind of answer:

```json
{
    "my_first_field": [
        "The first field had an error."
    ],
    "my_second_field": [
        "The second field had an error."
    ],
}
```

you need to raise a `ValidationError` in the validate_<field>() methods.

Note that doing so you won't be able to have a custom error heriting from `ValidationError` and with a `status_code` different of 400. Your `detail` message will be extract and a new `ValidationError` (with a default 400 `status_code`) raise.