# AWS Cognito for Django3 + DRF Authentication

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to set up an AWS Cognito backend
I have a React frontend already working with it, now I need my DRF API to authenticate using the Cognito as backend.

I have found a few Python packages for that, none of them seem to be actively maintained
[django-warrant](https://github.com/MetaMetricsInc/django-warrant) doesn't work with Django3 and is pretty much dead

[Django Cognito JWT](https://github.com/labd/django-cognito-jwt) seems to be my best bet,
but also not actively maintained, the documentation is very poor, and there is a [medium post](https://blog.labdigital.nl/introducing-django-cognito-jwt-for-django-rest-framework-efc7c1337728) on how to use, not very detailed, but better than nothing.

So, I tried to follow the documentation

Added the env vars on my settings

```py
COGNITO_AWS_REGION = 'us-east-1'
COGNITO_USER_POOL = 'us-east-1_xxxxxxx'  # same user pool id I'm using on the React app
COGNITO_AUDIENCE = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' # the same client id I'm using on the React app
```

Then on my DRF authentication classes:

```py
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'django_cognito_jwt.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],
```

And finally the user model:

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.MyUser'
COGNITO_USER_MODEL = "accounts.MyUser"
```

My custom User Model:

```py
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()
```

I'm also using DRF JWT package, and if I try to login with a Cognito user, something like:

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"email":"user@invalid.com","password":"secretpassword"}' http://localhost/api-token-auth/`

I get an error

`{"non_field_errors":["Unable to log in with provided credentials."]}`

On another hand, if I try to login with a local Django user via Django Rest Framework JWT it works fine and I get the JWT token as a response, so I guess the issue is the Cognito integration.

Any idea what I'm missing? or how can I debug in order to figure out what is happening?

**UPDATE**

After digging a bit more on the code, I found out a few things:

Even doing a DRF JWT authentication, the code end up at:
django/contrib/auth/**init**.py
Where it loops through all the authentication backends for Django, not for DRF:

```py
for backend, backend_path in _get_backends(return_tuples=True):
```

Still using the `ModelBackend` to authenticate the user.

So, I guess I also need to add some Cognito authentication backend for Django.
I checked if I could just use the same backend used on DRF, but then I got an error of invalid argument:
`TypeError: authenticate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'email'`

*UPDATE 2*
It seems that one of the issues is because I use email instead of username to authenticate, and none of the packages seems to support it

Comment: is one of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076254/drf-auth-token-non-field-errors-unable-to-log-in-with-provided-credential) answers as suitable for your problem?

Comment: nope, those answers are not related to AWS Cognito

Comment: are you sure the problems is exactly with Cognito? That's a default DRF message, not a specific one for Cognito.

Comment: Yes, the authentication through DRF JWT works, I'll update the question with this information

Comment: did you get your setup working? also struggling with react and drf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, there are 2 steps to achieve your goal.

1. Get IdToken and AccessToken from Cognito by Boto3 library.
2. Apply the IdToken in this Pattern `Authorization Bearer IdToken` to call API  via `curl`.

Unlike `rest_framework_jwt` , `django_cognito_jwt` only deals with JWT token at header. `django_cognito_jwt` does not cover step 1. That is why you are getting this error  `TypeError: authenticate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'email'`.

So, solution is use boto3 to get `IdToken` and apply `curl` by passing `Authorization:Bearer IdToken` header.